# Ver si un checkbox fue seleccionado en PHP

Tags: php, html

Quiero validar y ejecutar código **PHP** según se le de click al ***checkbox*** o no.
En el formulario esto esto:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="marcado">
<input type="submit" name="">
```

Y en el **PHP** tengo:

```
if (!empty($_POST['checkbox'])) {
    echo "MARCADO";
    echo "<br/>";
    echo $_POST['checkbox'];
} else {
    echo "ERROR";
    echo "<br/>";
    echo $_POST['checkbox'];
}
```

Pero siempre muestra el mensaje **ERROR**, al darle click o no al ***checkbox***.

Comment: Y que tiene que ver checbox1 con usuario??

Comment: Hola, para ver un checkbox marcado en php deberías hacer `if ($_POST['checkbox1']!=null) {` no `if (!empty($_POST['usuario'])) {`.Saludos.

Comment: @Carmen wow!! Si, gracias, ya actualicé la pregunta. Gracias.

Comment: Accede por el nombre checkbox1, no por checkbok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

¿Es necesario el uso de PHP? Una forma muy sencilla de hacerlo es utilizar jQuery, de modo que sea un AJAX el que se encargue de tal petición. Para ello sería necesario añadirle un id al checkbox:

```
<input id="cbx1" type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="marcado">
<input type="submit" name="">
```

Y el jQuery en cuestión:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#cbx1").click(function() {
       if ($(this).is(":checked")){
         doChecked(); // Función si se checkea
       } else {
         doNotChecked(); //Función si no
       }
   });
});
```

Comment: Parece que has cambiado tu pregunta mientras estaba escribiendo mi respuesta. Antes no tenía nada que ver con SQL Injection. Lo dejo por si te sirve igual.

Comment: Si, es que con tantas pruebas no cambié el nombre del checkbox. Fue un error de mi parte. Y con respecto a tu respuesta no sabía esa validación con jQuery, la tomaré en cuenta. Pero se debe validar siempre del lado del servidor como una capa más de seguridad. Por eso mi consulta.

Comment: @Piropeator Es que cuando he empezado a escribir la pregunta yo me había quedado solo con la copla del título **Quiero validar y ejecutar código según se le de click al checkbox o no**. Mea culpa.

Comment: pido las disculpas del caso.

Comment: Solo como detalle, SIEMPRE hay que validar el lado del servidor. El lado de cliente es opcional. Mejora la interacción con el usuario pero es más fácil de saltarse esta ultima

Answer (score 1):

```
if (isset($_POST["checkbox1"])) {
   echo $_POST["checkbox1"];
} else {
   echo "error";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ejemplo de Como hacer un Checkbox y al seleccionarlo mostrar el valor de la variable en un input CON PHP, Ejecútese en un ".php" no en ".html".

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <script>
function myFunction(valor) {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
  var text = document.getElementById("text");
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    document.getElementById("text").value = valor;
  } else {
     document.getElementById("text").value = valor;
  }
}
</script>
  <body>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>CheckBox</td>
    <td>Valor</td>
  </tr>

  <?php for ($i=0; $i <4 ; $i++) {
    $valor=0;
  ?>
<tr>

<td><input name="checkbox1"type="checkbox" id="myCheck"
 <?php  if (isset($_POST["checkbox1"])) {
   $var='';
} else {
   $var=$i;
}

?>  onclick="myFunction(<?php echo "$var"; ?>)" ></td>
<td><?php echo "$i"; ?><td>


</tr>
  <?php

}

 ?>

<?php echo $valor ?>

</table>
<input type="text" id="text" onclick="myFunction();" value="">
  </body>

</html>
```